# How do I properly create, write or unlink records for many2many field using the new API?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Can someone give me an example to manipulate a many2many field using the new API? I've tried to read the [Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html) to no avail.

Here are my example classes:

```python
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class example_class_one(models.Model):

    _name           = "example.class.one"

    name           = fields.Char('Name')
    value          = fields.Float('Value')

example_class_one()

class example_class_two(models.Model):

    _name           = "example.class.two"

    name                = fields.Char('Name')
    example_class_ones  = fields.Many2many('example.class.one',string='Example Class Ones')

    @api.one
    def test(self):
        #CREATES SOME example_class_ones and assign them to self
        #MANIPULATE SOME example_class_ones and save them
        #DELETE SOME example_class_ones from self
        pass

example_class_two()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Odoo 8 the new ORM API is much nicer that the previous one (with all these boring (cr, uid, ids, ..) parameters). One of the big advantages for me with this new API is the fact that we are now working with **objects**, not **ids**.

All you need with the new methods is the `self` parameter. You can iterate over it - it's among other things also a collection of odoo objects.

And there is also one magic variable - `self.env` which is of type Environment and contains all this `cr, uid, etc.` stuff. It contains also a collection of all known models - that's what you need.

So why don't you try this way:

```
@api.one
def test(self):
    model_one = self.env['example.class.one']
    model_one.create({'name': 'Some ONE object', 'value': 2.0})
    ones = model_one.browse([1, 3, 5])
    ones2 = model_one.search([('name', '=', 'Some name')])
    # You can imagine - search() return also objects! :)
    ones2[0].unlink()
    # Or, to deal with you many2many field...
    self.example_class_ones += model_one.new({
        'name': 'New comer to the many2many relation',
        'value': 666.0})
```

Hope that answers you question.

Comment: can I do this: `self.example_class_ones.delete()` to delete all the example_class_ones in self?

Comment: I got this error `AttributeError: 'example.class.one' object has no attribute 'delete'`

Comment: Because it's not delete, it's unlink(). Sorry for this mistake. I'm correcting the answer now.

Comment: Thank you! You've been really helpful. If you don't mind, you can try to answer another question of mine, this one is harder I think. Just take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475648/odoo-method-synchronization-compute-method-collision

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my case as below, 
either on `@api`

```
@api.onchange('opportunity_id')
    def _get_description(self):
        if self.opportunity_id.id:
            self.x_description = self.opportunity_id.x_description
```

or declare as setup relationship and field (related) as link below

[Pass custom field values from oppertunity to quotation in odoo 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973852/pass-custom-field-values-from-oppertunity-to-quotation-in-odoo-10/44187494#44187494)